# Unable to curl or wget an image from remote URL

Tags: facebook, curl, command-line, wget, imagedownload

I am just trying to download an image from Facebook from the command-line (in Mac OSX)

Any ideas as to why I can't curl an image from Facebook?

```
curl -O https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/v/t34.0-12/s720x720/10361106_862849933729442_781906896_n.jpg?oh=180f721d0cd3107253c49448dffda02a&oe=537C1807
```

When I try curl, I get the html instead of the image (I am guessing because it doesn't have the image extension).

When I try wget, I get an error:

```
ERROR: The certificate of 'scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of 'scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

Is there a way I can fix this? I specifically want that image! Thanks.

Comment: I am getting 403 Forbidden error. Please let me know how do you resolve it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wget` instead of `curl`:

```
wget --accept .jpg,.jpeg --cookies=on -p "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/v/t34.0-12/s720x720/10361106_862849933729442_781906896_n.jpg?oh=180f721d0cd3107253c49448dffda02a&oe=537C1807" -O "image.jpg"
```

Comment: I am getting the same error that I stated above when I tried using wget. Did you successfully run that command?

Comment: I ran this successfully under Cygwin, but on my MacBook Pro, I get a 403 Forbidden error. Strange...

Comment: @Tobi That didn't work on Ubuntu platform. Any alternative?